# Excel: change the spreadsheets from templates to workbooks?

Tags: excel

I have a set od Excel (2003) sheets saved as ".xlt" format.
Now ,how to  change the spreadsheets from templates to workbooks?

Further can any one make it clear what is a Excel  workbook and what is Excel template?
Differences?

Does not a workbook contain multiple worksheets?

Thanks and Regards

Vas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between templates and workbooks is the extension. If you rename the .xlt to .xls it will change from a template to a workbook.

The only functional difference is that the .xlt's default action is to open a copy of itself as a new file.

Answer (score 1):

Double-Click on the template in Windows Explorer and it should open as a workbook which you can save.

Templates have many times been described as the cookie cutter and the workbook is the resulting cookie which now has the same shape as the template. They both may contain multiple worksheets.

We had an app that looped through a recordset and created multiple workbooks (one for each client.). They all had the same look, formating, etc. because they were all based on the same template.

Comment: does a workbook save as ".xls" format and worksheet as ".xlt" format?

Comment: you can save a workbook with a single worksheet as an .xls file, but an .xlt file is a template (thought you caught that on the anwer you approved).